# Счетчик репостов facebook в плагине яндекса "Поделиться"

Tags: javascript, facebook, share, ya-share2

На сайте в плагине яндекса "Поделиться" перестал отображаться счетчик репостов для facebook. Для остальных соц.сетей отображаются. В документации прочитал что есть такой атрибут data-access-token(Токен для снятия ограничения запросов на получение счетчика. Актуален и работает только для Facebook. Токен, полученный от Facebook. Как получить токен см. в статье https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens.)
Прочитав статью и документацию я не понял как это сделать, очень все запутано.
Может кто-нибудь простыми словами объяснить как получить этот токен?

Answer (score 1):

Токен не при чем. Фейсбук поменял метод получения количества репостов. Яндекс и Рамблер уже месяц не могут откорректировать свои скрипты.